# ssl: several certificates from single private key?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create a CA using openssl.

Why do I need to first create a private key:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 1024
```

And then create the certificate?

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

As far as I know, a certificate is a public key signed by a private key?

1. Where is public key?
2. Can I then create several certificates from one private key? Does it mean, I'm able to create several public keys?

Comment: A certificate _contains_ a publickey, but it is not just a signed publickey. (Nor is it a signed CSR as many uninformed people believe.) All OpenSSL privatekey file formats, including the 'legacy' PKCS1 written by `genrsa`, include publickey; see e.g. `openssl rsa -text <ca.key`. There is one publickey per privatekey, but you can have more than one cert for that keypair precisely because there is other info in the cert which differs, although for a CA this is mostly useless. SO is now only for programming and development which this is not, so it belongs on security.SX.

Comment: You can do this but it isn't a good idea. If your private key gets compromised you will have to alter *N* certificates instead of one.